# What is the best way of detecting whether two strings differ by one one character?

Tags: java

I have this code, but it seems pretty unwieldy. Is there a more canonical way of doing so in Java?

```
public boolean oneDiff(String from, String s) {
    if (from.length()!=s.length()) return false;
    int differences = 0;
    for (int charIndex = 0;charIndex<from.length();charIndex++) {
        if (from.charAt(charIndex)!=s.charAt(charIndex)) differences++;
    }
    return (differences==1);
}
```

Comment: You could at least optimize your solution to return false once differences > 1 within the for loop

Comment: Do you need to consider the case where one string is a single character either prepended or appended to the other string?

Comment: firstString.compare(secondString); will get you a lexographical comparison, although I'm not sure that's exactly what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with @mk. However to minimize the loop execution you should not run the loop till the string ends. Instead you can break the loop as soon as the difference becomes greater than 1. Like this:

> ```
> for (int charIndex = 0;charIndex<from.length();charIndex++) {
>         if (from.charAt(charIndex)!=s.charAt(charIndex)) differences++;
>         if(differences > 1) break;
>     }
>     return (differences==1);
> ```

This will help in faster execution by loop optimization if this is what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Nope, that really is the best way!

There's nothing built-in because this isn't something you need to do often. The closest trick is doing an xor on two integers, and then getting the Hamming Weight using `bitCount`, in order to check for how many flipped bits they have in common:

```
Integer.bitCount(int1 ^ int2)
```

But there's nothing like that for Strings - it's not a common case, so you have to code your own. And the way you've coded it seems fine - you really do have to loop over every character. I guess you could shorten the variable names and remove the parens around your return, but that's just cosmetic.